# Android Studio emulator is not scaling after update

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with Android Studio emulator. Two weeks ago I updated Android Studio to v2.3.3 using its update module and I installed some packages from SDK manager. Now every time I run a virtual machine with AVD, it will appear like this:
[image: emulator interface]

My laptop has a 4k display and this problem arises after updating Android Studio.
I tried to replace emulator directory with the old version but nothing changed.

Comment: One of the packages you downloaded from SDK manager might be the emulator itself, which is independent from your Android Studio version. Which version of the emulator you're using?

Comment: Android Emulator v26.1.2. I replaced its folder with the original one from Android Studio bundle but it did fix it.

Comment: I'm new to android studio, but having the same exact issue... since there is no answer... can someone guide me on how to solve it?